# How to pass form-data with rest-client

Tags: ruby, rest-client

I am trying to translate a post request I send to a server with Postman to ruby RestClient.

In Postman, I send a (successful) `POST` request with a URL with params.
In my `headers` I have one parameter
Under `Body` I send more parameters under `form-data`. I tried adding these to the payload, which does not work:

I tried to translate it to the following call with [rest-client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client)

```
url = "https://..."
cookie = "..."

payload = {
    payloadParam: "some param",
    formDataParam: "form-data param"
}
headers = {
    Cookie: cookie
}
```

Following their docs I then fired the following call:

```
data = RestClient.post(url, payload, headers)
```

So this doesn't pass the form-data params correctly. I have a feeling I am supposed to pass these parameters through something other than the payload, but I can't find any docs online explaining how. All I could find is a multipart example of loading an external file, but I don't have an external file.

How do I add form-data params to a POST request with Rest-Client?

My cURL structure looks like this:

```
curl -X POST \
  'https://.../?payloadParam=xxxxxxxx' \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Length: 55' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'Cookie: xxxxxxxx' \
  -H 'Host: xxxxxxxx.com' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
  -H 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.19.0' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d 'formDataParam=xxxxx&secondFormDataParam=yyyyy'
```

Comment: `this doesn't pass the form-data params correctly` per say what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Amit, I am not getting the same response as I do with Postman. I actually don't have to use form-data. I can use x-www-form-urlencoded. Still, the params tat go into it - where do you pass those? I think it's not in the payload, but where? It needs to be in the body, but how do you pass params to the request body with restclient?

Comment: Postman has provision to convert request into `curl`. Can you please share how `curl` request look like?

Comment: @AmitPatel, added to question. Please have a look.